# Invoke default constructor for each element in constructed std::vector

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

Is there a way to construct `std::vector<C>` of N elements by invoking the default constructor for each?

The constructor from `size_type` just calls `C`'s constructor once and then uses its copy constructor for the rest of the elements.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're stuck with C++03? If not, then there is no problem to solve.

Comment: Indeed, I was using Xcode's default GNU C++ stdlib (default for older deployment targets at least), which includes the older version of std::vector. With LLVM's stdlib there is indeed no issue.

Comment: If you set `-std=c++11` then stdlib should do the right thing too, unless it is very old.

Comment: It doesn't seem to, at least not with a deployment target of OS X 10.7. The compatibility version of <vector> is included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The constructor from size_type just calls C's constructor once and
>   then uses its copy constructor for the rest of the elements.

Not true since `C++11`. Look at [std::vector::vector documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> ...
>
> vector( size_type count, 
>                    const T& value,
>                    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()); (2)
>
> explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); (3)
>
> ...

And then:

> ...
>
> 2) Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value
>   value.
>
> 3) Constructs the container with count default-inserted
>   instances of T. No copies are made.
>
> ...

So you need the 3rd constructor `std::vector<C>(size)`

---

It seems like this behavior exists only since `c++11`.

I can't find a way of doing this before `c++11`. Since no constructor can do this, the option would have been to create an empty vector, reserve and then `emplace_back` elements. But `emplace_back` is since `c++11` so... we're back to square one.

Comment: @KerrekSB didn't know that

Comment: Yeah. C++11 with cleaned up a bunch of stuff like that. With its allegedly more useful allocator model, more allocator constructors were added everywhere, and default arguments were removed in the same wash, presumably to help avoid overload ambiguities. In any case, C++11 now makes default arguments much less relevant, since the new delegating constructors allow user code to define multiple constructor overloads easily (though the vector case doesn't delegate).

Comment: Indeed, I was using an stdlib with C++03 support.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
std::vector<C> v(size)
```

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class C{
    public:
    C(){
        std::cout << "constructor\n";
    }
    C(C const&){
        std::cout << "copy/n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<C> v(10);

}
```

**Result:** (C++11/14)

```
constructor 
constructor 
constructor 
constructor
constructor
constructor 
constructor
constructor
constructor
constructor
```

**Results:** (C++98)

```
constructor
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
copy
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/4nwr)